# How can I make program to add all numbers in array?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

```java
public static int add(int [] arr , int index){
  int count=0;

  if(arr.length == index)
    return count/arr.length;

  if(index< arr.length)
    count+=arr[index];

  return count + add(arr,index+1);

}
```

So the problem is I want this code add al the numbers in array but this code doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you share more about what's happening? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: When you say the code "aint work", what do you mean? Do you get a compiler error, the wrong result, something else?
Please provide some details as to what you have tried, what you expected to happen and what actually happened.
Here is a starting point. What is the name of your first parameter? where is this used within the function?
Here is another starting point - if you want to add up all of the elements in an array, you might need to use a loop of some kind.

Comment: Hello, the code  isn't error, so i will explain all the code first, a couple minutes ago, i trying to run this code, but he return with wrong result , example i have array {50,50,80} , the result is 180, yes it add all the numbers , but the code not divide the result by the arr.length, thanks before

Comment: Are you sure you have run the code you posted? Have a look at my starting points.
Here is another one - You don't need to **return return** a result. Only one return is required. Two returns should give a compiler error.
Also, how are you calling it? If you pass the length of the array as the second parameter, the function will **return return** 0 - disregarding the mismatched variable name issue (which probably isn't going to be the sum of all of the elements).
In short provide some details that allow us to help you. Remember, we cannot see your screen.

Comment: So i expecting the code will return add all the numbers in arr and divided by arr.length,The parameter is arr (sorry you have to change array to arr), and index always 0 , u know how to use looping like for to add and divide it, but iwant to use recursion,  oh sorry ,the last return should be return count+ add(arr,index+1).

Comment: Sorry if you dont understand my english, and im basic at java, i just want to understand more about recursion.thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to write recursive functions. One common way is to

1. Use an accumulator to carry (accumulete) intermediate values.
2. Use a "bootstrap" function to get it going.

In reference to my example, the `recursiveAdd` function simply takes the list of integers to be **averaged**. This function then calls the recursive function with the correct initial values - index = 0 and accumulator = 0.

Looking at the recursive function from the bottom up, It calls itself with the array and increments the index to the next element. It also passes the accumulated value + the value of the current element.

The second (actually the first) thing that the recursive function `_add` does is to check if we have reached the end of the list. If we have, it will return the accumulator (which will hold the sum of every element in the array) back out to the "bootstrap function" `recursiveAdd` where the result will be divided by the length of the array to calculate the average and return that result to the caller.

A couple of notes. Since you are dividing by the number of elements in the list, you might want to use `double` as the return type (rather than `int`) from the bootstrap function (e.g. what if your array was {1, 1, 0}). Also consider what might happen if there are a large number of elements in the array.

```java
public class RecursiveAdder {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int  [] x = { 1, 2, 3};
        int [] y = { 10, 20, 30, 40};
        System.out.println(recursiveAdd(x));
        System.out.println(recursiveAdd(y));

    }

    public static int recursiveAdd(int [] x) {
        return _add(x, 0, 0) / x.length;
    }

    public static int _add(int x [], int index, int accumulator) {
        if (index == x.length) {
            return accumulator;
        }

        return _add(x, index+1, x[index] + accumulator);
    }
}
```

FWIW, your example is only dividing the last element by the length of the array. And even then, it is not dividing the value of the last element by the length, it is dividing count by the length and count was just initialised to zero. So your function is just returning 0 for the last element.